# Создать динамический TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

Есть готовые статичные TextView

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/new_york"
                style="@style/editTextEntryName"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom_of_textview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height_of_textview"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/main2Color"
                android:text="New York"
                android:background="@drawable/back_city_red"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_check_box_black_24dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/philadelphia"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom_of_textview"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/filColor"
                style="@style/editTextEntryName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height_of_textview"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Philadelphia"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
                />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Puerto_Rico"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom_of_textview"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/filColor"
                style="@style/editTextEntryName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height_of_textview"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Puerto Rico"
                android:background="@drawable/back_city"
                />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/San_Francisco"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom_of_textview"
                style="@style/editTextEntryName"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/filColor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height_of_textview"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="San Francisco"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
                />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Miami"
                style="@style/editTextEntryName"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/filColor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height_of_textview"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Miami"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

и есть список городов с уникальными id-шками, подскажите как реализовать динамический список TextView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использовать RecyclerView, если по каким то причинам вам это не подходит, добавлять TextView программно, методом [addView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams))

Comment: попробую RecyclerView